# Convert fileSystem object to json and xml

Tags: java, json, xml, composite, template-method-pattern

I have created an arraylist with `fileSystem` using the Composite pattern. The file system has folders and files. The folder can also have folders. Using the template method, I need to create classes that convert a `fileSystem` object into two formats: `json` and `xml`. How do I convert a `fileSystem` object into json and xml?

Comment: Component fileSystem = new Directory(" file System");
        Component diskC = new Directory("disk C");
        Component pngFile = new File("12345.png");
        Component docxFile = new File("Document.docx");
        diskC.Add(pngFile);
        diskC.Add(docxFile);
        fileSystem.Add(diskC);

Comment: Please add your code to the question itself rather than to the comments

Comment: i need help how convert object who have directory in directory ... and this directory have file into json. like return { name + "{" ..... } }?  help pls